# Running a python file inside another python file (without classes and functions)

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a simple python file, p1.py which has basically this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
a=1
b=2
c=3
s1=a+b
s2=a+c
s3=b+c
```

In my second file, p2.py, I want to access values of s1, s2 and s3. I tried following my second file but it wont work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import os.path
import math
import sys
import subprocess

os.system('python p1.py')
print('the value of first variable is' + s1 + 'second is' +s2 + 'and third is' + s3)
```

I have also tried using

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'p1.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

but i can't access values of `s1, s2 or s3` in from my second file. I read up on other solutions where most people suggested using class with functions but I have hundreds of line of variables `(a,b,c)` and results `(s1,s2, s3)` etc in first file so reading and executing directly seemed only option.

Comment: "Executing" the file does so in a separate process. The best option is to `import p1`.

Answer (score 4):

Other people suggesting using classes and functions are right on a higher level. It's all about good design that makes your code easier to read, use, extend and maintain.

That being said, to achieve what you want to achieve, you can just do:

```py
# In p2.py:
import p1

print("The value of s1 is" + p1.s1)
```

The `import` statement will load the `p1` file and execute all the module-level statements in it, and make the declared variables available to you. If you don't want to prefix everything with `p1.` then you could do `from p1 import *` but then things get really messy really fast.

Comment: This is geniuinely a great answer..! 

Comment: This is a simple yet great answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have not printed out anything or wrote the output in any files? Then how can you access them? Without a calling??

Try something like this, if this is what you're looking for..

```
cmd = "python p1.py"

log = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '),stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


stdout,stderr = log.communicate()

# FORMAT THE OUTPUT

stdout = stdout.decode('utf-8')
stderr = stderr.decode('utf-8')

s1,s2,s3 = list(stdout.split('\n'))
```

and your p1.py should print

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
a=1 
b=2 
c=3 
s1=a+b 
s2=a+c 
s3=b+c
print(s1)
print(s2)
print(s3)
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer. Printing it in the original file (p1.py) did the trick.